# Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred. events=0x8

Tags: android, android-emulator, crash

`02-12 18:48:57.049: E/InputQueue-JNI(4659): channel '2be9da40 com.forwardapps.liveItems.LiveItemsService (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8`

I'm getting this error in `Ice Cream Sandwidth(ICS)` whenever I set my livewallpaper as the background. It works fine on all other versions of android.

Does anyone know what's going on here or could they explain it?

Comment: I just saw this when my activity got destroyed without dismissing a context menu. Is this the same flow you're following?

Comment: I just saw this when relaunching an Activity (using 'getIntent' and 'finish').  It doesn't seem to actually cause a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a try, catch block around the code that draws the canvas.

More specifically:

```
Canvas canvas = null;

    try {
        canvas = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
        synchronized (_surfaceHolder) 
        {
            onDraw(canvas);
        }

        if(canvas != null)
        {
            _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: OK, marked as the correct answer, but what was the problem in the first place?

Comment: I'm seeing this answer (because I had a similar error) and it doesn't make much sense to me: did you perhaps meant "place a try/finally (not try/catch) in drawcanvas? In this way you can put the unlock in the finally block and be sure(Tm) that the lock is release.

Comment: This answer is not help

Answer (score 3):

Are you actually seeing a problem, or just being troubled by the error message?  This message is printed I believe when the client side of the input event pipe fails because the server has closed the connection.  This could happen for example if you don't close a window when your activity is being destroyed.

Comment: I see this connection in the x86 emulator when I'm waiting for a GPS lock.  (the device appears to be configured to send static GPS coordinates)