# App mysteriously closes after an hour

Tags: android, android-webview, android-video-player

Whilst debugging my application, after about an hour, I got the following messages in LogCat:

```
10-25 12:27:37.180  13308-13308/com.my.app E/InputEventReceiver﹕ channel '42294e98 com.my.app/com.my.app.MainActivity (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9

10-25 12:27:37.180  13308-13308/com.my.app E/InputEventReceiver﹕ channel '42742bf0 com.my.app/com.my.app.PlaylistActivity (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9

10-25 12:27:37.180  13308-13308/com.my.app E/InputEventReceiver﹕ channel '425a3258 com.my.app/com.my.app.WebViewActivity (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
```

Any idea what caused this? There were no other major errors before this (there are some errors related the the videoview I think, but nothing that has yet caused the app to crash or stop working)

Comment: are you passing context as a parameter to any class?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251649/publisher-closed-input-channel-or-an-error-occurred-events-0x8

Comment: StinePike - I think so yea, I'd need to check (I'm new to Android and this is a complex project haha). Why would this cause any problems? The app was going solid for an hour before it died (with no interaction btw, it sits and runs on its own)

Comment: test it on other devices too just to confirm if its a firmware issue or else it the code causing the issue.

Comment: I have tested it on my phone (Galaxy S3) and it seems much more stable, lasted for approx 2 hrs before I simply had to leave the office. If this is hardware related, what difference in hardware would be causing this?

Comment: Just to add, I went through my activity that is active 99% of the time and changed any instances of "this" to "getapplicationcontext()" using the information from the link Brontok provided. It doesn't seemed to have helped :(